# Python/sed to get data between first and the last occurrence of a pattern in a file

Tags: python, regex, linux, awk, sed

I need to parse through log file and then find data between the first occurrence of a pattern and the last occurrence of a pattern in that files

example :

cat log1 ( for pattern tom )

```
tom dsdsdsd
ssadsds
fdfdf
erdfdf
df  dsfdsd
sfsfsf
dsds dsad
sdsdsd
tom aasasasa
da da dad  
sfsfsadadadad
```

Should give :

```
tom dsdsdsd
ssadsds
fdfdf
erdfdf
df  dsfdsd
sfsfsf
dsds dsad
sdsdsd
tom aasasasa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file contains only two occurrences of `tom`, you could use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/tom/,/tom/p'
```

However, as @Andrey pointed out, that may not be the case. This is ugly, but uses `sed` again:

```
sed -n '/tom/=' file.txt | sed -n '1h;${x;G;s/\n/,/;s/$/p/p}' | xargs -I{} sed -n {} file.txt
```

Comment: doesn't work if there are other occurrences of the pattern, e.g. inserting 3rd `tom` in between existing ones would print the lines after the last occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `awk` (please note double arguments):

```
awk -v pat='tom' '
# save the first and the last occurrences of the pattern
(ARGIND == 1 && $0 ~ pat){if (!first) first = FNR; last = FNR}
# output everything between the first and the last occurrences of the pattern
(ARGIND == 2 && (FRN >= first || FNR <= last) ){print $0}
# skip the remaining lines
(ARGIND == 2 && FNR > last){exit}
' log.txt log.txt
```

For a special case of only two occurrences of the pattern in the file, this should be faster:

```
awk -v pat='tom' '
# detect pattern; if the second occurrence, output the line and exit
($0 ~ pat){if (first++) { print $0 ; exit} }
# output all lines after the first occurrence
(first){print $0}
' log.txt
```